# SharePoint Online ( Start automatically when an item is changed)

Tags: designer-workflow

I have created a custom list, with an approval workflow on it.

Now I want to copy the list item to another list once the workflow status changes to "Approved".

So I created another workflow on the same list and selected the option to copy the list item when it has changed.

But when Approval status changed from "In progress" state to "Approval" the workflow does not start automatically.

Comment: Why don't you just embed copying part to your first workflow?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the condition parameter of the workflow to match your list status.  The workflow will not run because it is looking for the status "Approved" not "Approval"